# How split the Toolbar?

Tags: java, android, toolbar

I am trying to split the toolbar so I get a Bottom bar.
I got the Toolbar to work, but cant find how to split it.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="#FF4444" />
```

and here is my .java.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

}
```

**EDIT**:

This is what I did, I got 2 toolbars, one in top, one in bottom, but I dont know if it is the right way to go.

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="#FF4444" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbarBottom"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="#FF4444" />
```

Comment: There is no built-in support for the old "split action bar" model. You would need to set up multiple `Toolbar` widgets yourself.

Comment: I did a edit now, think I got this right  I think.